# Unable to build Angular project in Alpine Linux

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, webpack, alpine-linux

I've recently migrated my project to Angular 13. It builds locally on my Mac, however it's started to fail when I run it in my Docker build container (tested both locally and on our CI/CD server.

It's complaining about the DeckGL import:

```
Cannot find module '@deck.gl/layers' or its corresponding type declarations.

1 import * as Layers from '@deck.gl/layers';

Cannot find module '@deck.gl/geo-layers' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import * as GeoLayers from '@deck.gl/geo-layers';

Cannot find module '@deck.gl/aggregation-layers' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import * as AggregationLayers from '@deck.gl/aggregation-layers';
```

I've used `npm list` to ensure the dependencies are the same on my Mac and within the Alpine container and have also tested using the same Node version (and have tried a couple of different Node / Apline images), however, the issue persists, whilst still working locally.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Really silly issue, but posting an answer in case someone runs into a similar issue in future.

I had accidentally run `npm install` in a top-level directory, and had installed some Node modules that didn't end up in my `package.json` file. In my case, I had the core `deck.gl` module installed in my `package.json`, but none of the layer packages (which are separate npm modules).

When I was running it locally, it was finding the correct dependency, but when running it on the CI/CD environment, it was obviously failing.